# Find tag text in xml

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following xml:

```
<a:something>text-a</a:something>
  <a:otherthing>text-b</a:otherthing>
```

and I want to assign a variable with the text of `<a:otherthing>`.

I tried `txt = xml.find("a:otherthing").text` but it shows me `SyntaxError: prefix 'a' not found in prefix map`

how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML shall somewhere above declare namespace for given prefix "a".

Note, that XML allows changing purpose of namespace few times in one document (but this is not used often).

Then you will find, that for "ns:a" there is something line "http://a.alfa.aa/a/aaa.aa" string, which is so called fully qualified namespace.

In your find you shall then use a namespace map in form of

```
nsmap = {"a": "http://a.alfa.aa/a/aaa.aa"}
xml.find("a:otherthing", namespaces=nsmap)
```